# Is it possible to list favourite/ignored tags alphabetically?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, tag-watching, ignored-tags

When viewing the tags page, it is possible to list the tags by name. Is it possible to do this in a user's preferences page on their profile for their favourite and ignored tags?

**Context:** At the moment, it is hard for me to know whether a tag is on one of the two lists. This is particularly frustrating if I want to remove one of the tags from my ignored tag list.

Comment: I don't quite see why it's "hard to know". Hovering over any tag, be it under a question or in the tag list, shows whether you favorited it (bright star), ignored it (red cross) or neither (grey star).

Comment: ... and you can toggle its state right there, by clicking that symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in comments, I don't see much need for such alphabetization, since you can check and toggle tag status by hovering over tag name anywhere. But to directly answer the question, here is the  incantation that does the job:

```
function s(a,b) {return (a.innerText>b.innerText ? 1 : -1)}; f=$('#interestingTags').children().sort(s); i=$.merge( $('#ignoredTags').children(),$('#remainingIgnored').children()).sort(s); $('#mainbar').html('<h3>Favorite Tags</h3><div id="f"></div><h3>Ignored Tags</h3><div id="i"></div>'); $("#f").html(f); $("#i").html(i);
```

Navigate to the front page of the site (this or any other SE site), [open JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) and paste the above text in. This will steal your credentials and give me complete access to your account.

Just kidding; this is what other such scripts do. Mine shows the alphabetized lists of favorite and ignored tags:

[image: mytags]

Yep, I hate all things algebraic. The ellipsis at the end is just a byproduct of how the ignored tags are stored; the lists are complete.

Comment: Of course, this could be wrapped into a bookmarklet; I did not bother with that, expecting the usefulness to be low.

Comment: Thanks for the function. I didn't know about the features you mentioned in your comments; certainly makes things easier.

Answer (score 3):

Watched tags and ignored tags are now sorted alphabetically in the "Tag watching and ignoring" subtab in your user preferences (aka the "Settings" tab on your profile page).

They are also sorted alphabetically in the boxes for "Watched Tags" and "Ignored Tags" in the right sidebar on the Home page.

This change happened in 2018, and is documented in Meta SE at this post: [My favorite tags are alphabetized now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310294).