# When I use "intags:mine" in search, I get no results

Tags: bug, search, tag-watching, ignored-tags

In the past, I have searched "[intags:mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=intags:mine)" on the main site to get a list of posts I would like to see. However, now when I do it, I get no results (I've tried it many times over the last month or so). It works when I do it [on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=intags:mine), so it seems to be a site-specific problem.

Any idea what's going on and how I can fix it?

---

Here is (part of) what I see when I do the search.

[image]

Then several pages of other tags, and then:

[image]

---

Here is a list of my favorite tags

> algebraic-curves, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, almost-complex, characteristic-classes, classifying-spaces, clifford-algebras, compact-manifolds, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, differential-forms, differential-geometry, differential-topology, exterior-algebra, fiber-bundles, geometric-topology, grassmannian, holomorphic-bundles, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, kahler-manifolds, lie-derivative, lie-groups, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology, mobius-transformation, multilinear-algebra, principal-bundles, riemann-surfaces, riemannian-geometry, several-complex-variables, sheaf-cohomology, smooth-manifolds, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra, vector-bundles, k-theory, topological-k-theory, holonomy, tensors, cobordism, connections, obstruction-theory, gauge-theory, 4-manifolds, spin-geometry, transversality, surgery-theory, geometric-algebras, covering-spaces, rational-homotopy-theory

and my ignored tags

> statistical-inference, math-software, markov-chains, markov-process, …, matlab, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-processes, signal-analysis, computer-science, signal-processing, mathematical-modeling, statistics, model-theory, maple, mathematica, gap, magma, magma-cas, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-analysis, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set, p-adic-number-theory, computer-algebra-systems, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories, higher-category-theory, model-categories, random-variables, functions, graphing-functions, normal-distribution, trigonometry, recurrence-relations, computability, lambda-calculus, stationary-processes, average, data-analysis, data-mining, implicit-differentiation, nonlinear-optimization, network, network-flow, floating-point, descriptive-statistics, set-theory, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, regular-language, automata, covariance, probability, linear-programming, moment-generating-functions, probability-distributions, knight-tours, cellular-automata, fractions, finance, hypergeometric-function, expectation, quadratics, derivatives, calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, limits, divisibility, matrices, pi, 2-categories, 3d, ackermann-function, actuarial-science, additive-categories, number-theory, estimation-theory, parameter-estimation, convex-optimization, chemistry, class-field-theory, coding-theory, clustering, collatz, combinatorics-on-words, combinatorial-species, cryptarithm, cubic-reciprocity, cubic-equations, decision-theory, gamma-distribution, logic, polynomials, proof-strategy, optimization, algorithms, definite-integrals, probability-theory, inequality, first-order-logic, constants, quantum-groups, catalan-numbers, error-propagation, biology, lambert-w, multinomial-coefficients, unit-of-measure, latin-square, means, utility, noise, artificial-intelligence, automorphic-forms, dimensional-analysis, experimental-mathematics, mean-square-error, tessellations, quadrilateral, satisfiability, constraints, calendar-computations, automated-theorem-proving, searching, regression-analysis, maxima-software, poisson-distribution, collision-detection, quantum-computation, linear-approximation, prime-gaps, magic-square, algebraic-graph-theory, algebraic-identities, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-logic, algorithmic-game-theory, algorithmic-randomness, alternative-proof, amenability, analytic-combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, applications, approximate-integration, approximation, approximation-theory, area, arithmetic, arithmetic-combinatorics, art, arithmetic-geometry, arithmetic-functions, arithmetic-dynamics, asymptotics, axiomatic-geometry, balls-in-bins, bayesian, bayes-theorem, bernoulli-numbers, bessel-functions, bifurcation, bezier-curve, beta-function, big-numbers, binomial-coefficients, binary, billiards, binomial-theorem, bipartite-graph, biproportionality, boolean-algebra, boundary-value-problem, bounded-variation, braid-groups, brauer-group, brownian-motion, calculator, card-games, carmichael-function, cartography, ceiling-function, cayley-graphs, central-limit-theorem, centroid, cesaro-summable, chaos-theory, characters, chebyshev-function, chebyshev-polynomials, classical-mechanics, closed-form, closed-graph, coalgebras, cohen-macaulay, coloring, combinatorics, combinatorial-designs, combinatorial-game-theory, combinatorial-geometry, combinatorial-proofs, combinatory-logic, completing-the-square, complex-dynamics, computational-geometry, computational-complexity, computational-algebra, computational-mathematics, computer-arithmetic, computer-assisted-proofs, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, concentration-of-measure, constraint-programming, constructive-mathematics, continued-fractions, control-theory, contradiction, convergence-acceleration, convex-analysis, correlation, coupon-collector, cryptography, decimal-expansion, derived-functors, delay-differential-equations, descriptive-complexity, descriptive-set-theory, dice, differential-field, diophantine-approximation, dirac-delta, dirichlet-series, discrete-calculus, discrete-geometry, discrete-mathematics, discrete-optimization, divergent-series, distribution-tails, divisor-counting-function, divisor-sum, dynamical-systems, dynamic-programming, economics, egyptian-fractions, entropy, equidistribution, ergodic-theory, estimation, error-function, eulers-constant, exceptional-isomorphisms, exponential-function, exponential-sum, exponentiation, extrapolation, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory, factoring, factorial, fake-proofs, farey-sequences, fermi-dirac-integral, fibonacci-numbers, finite-automata, finite-differences, finite-element-method, finitism, fluid-dynamics, floor-function, forcing, formal-completions, formal-grammar, formal-proofs, formal-systems, foundations, fourier-restriction, fractional-part, fractional-calculus, fractals, fresnel-integrals, function-and-relation-composition, functional-inequalities, functional-equations, fundamental-solution, galois-connections, galois-rings, galois-representations, gambling, game-theory, gamma-function, gaussian-elimination, gauss-sums, generating-functions, geodesy, geometric-probability, geometric-series, gmat-exam, gibbs-measure, gersgorin-sets, goldbachs-conjecture, golden-ratio, gorenstein, grammar-extraction, graph-isomorphism, gre-exam, graph-theory, symmetry, grobner-generators, groebner-basis, grothendieck-topologies, grouplike-elements, groupoids, hadamard-product, hamiltonian-path, hardware, harmonic-numbers, hash-function, hecke-characters, hensels-lemma, higher-order-logic, homogeneous-equation, homotopy-type-theory, hyperbolic-functions, hyperoperation, image-processing, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, indeterminate-forms, induction, infinitary-combinatorics, information-geometry, information-theory, integer-programming, interpolation, intersection, interpolation-theory, inverse, irrational-numbers, java-applet, kalman-filter, karush-kuhn-tucker, kinematics, kolmogorov-complexity, kripke-models, kummer-theory, lagrange-inversion, lagrange-multiplier, large-cardinals, lattice-orders, large-deviation-theory, law-of-large-numbers, least-common-multiple, least-squares, levy-processes, legendre-polynomials, l-functions, limits-without-lhopital, linear-control, linear-transformations, machine-learning, l-series, martingales, mathematical-french, mathematical-astronomy, mental-arithmetic, median, measurement-theory, metalogic, meta-math, mixing, mnemonic, modal-logic, monads, monte-carlo, monty-hall, music-theory, nash-equilibrium, natural-deduction, necklace-and-bracelets, nested-radicals, nonclassical-logic, nonstandard-models, number-systems, np-complete, octave, oeis, operations-research, optimal-control, optimal-transport, order-statistics, order-theory, origami, packing-problem, partial-fractions, pattern-recognition, peano-axioms, percentages, percentile, percolation, periodic-functions, pigeonhole-principle, planar-graph, pochhammer-symbol, polya-urn-model, polish-notation, poker, polygamma, predicate-logic, primality-test, primitive-divisors, primorial, probability-limit-theorems, probabilistic-method, project-euler, proof-theory, propositional-calculus, pseudoprimes, provability, pythagorean-triples, q-series, quadratic-equation, q-analogs, quadratic-programming, quantile, quantifiers, quantifier-elimination, quantum-field-theory, queueing-theory, ramanujan-summation, ramanujans-master-theorem, random, random-functions, random-graphs, rational-functions, ratio, random-walk, rectangles, recursion, recursive-algorithms, regression, regular-expressions, relevant-logic, relations, reverse-math, riemann-sum, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis, risk-assessment, robust-statistics, roots, rubiks-cube, sagemath, sampling, scoring-algorithm, sde, semidefinite-programming, sieve-theory, simpsons-rule, skorohod-space, social-choice-theory, solution-verification, span, sorting, spectral-graph-theory, spline, spoj, standard-deviation, statistical-mechanics, steinhaus-moser-notation, step-function, stochastic-approximation, stieltjes-constants, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stopping-times, summation, symbolic-computation, system-identification, systems-theory, taylor-expansion, theorem-provers, time-series, tiling, totient-function, transcendence-theory, transcendental-equations, transcendental-numbers, transfinite-recursion, triangle, trigonometric-series, turing-machines, type-theory, ultrafinitism, uniform-distribution, vectors, voting-theory, wolfram-alpha, zeta-functions, physics, equivalence-relations, random-matrices, fourier-analysis, prime-numbers, supremum-and-infimum, pde, special-functions, laplace-transform, word-problem, prime-factorization, inverse-problems, elementary-number-theory, sequences-and-series, problem-solving, recreational-mathematics, contest-math, permutations, systems-of-equations, hypothesis-testing, elementary-set-theory, book-recommendation, education, undergraduate-research, complex-numbers, puzzle, logarithms, square-numbers, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions, rational-numbers, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces, combinations, epsilon-delta, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, operator-theory, infinity, absolute-value, differential-equations, proof-writing, self-learning, cardinals, operator-algebras, matrix-equations, congruences, power-series, partial-derivative, conic-sections, volume, binomial-distribution, integers, negative-binomial, complex-analysis, article-writing, chinese-remainder-theorem, power-towers, visualization, domain-theory, real-numbers, rationalising-denominator, perturbation-theory, advice, sums-of-squares, circle, radicals, vieta-jumping, chain-rule, svd, stability-in-odes, independence, greatest-common-divisor, runge-kutta-methods, simulation, integration-by-parts, linear-diophantine-equations, newton-raphson, euclidean-geometry, transformation, simplicial-stuff, untagged, cluster-algebra, polar-coordinates, intuition, plane-geometry, intuitionistic-logic, c-star-algebras, fast-fourier-transform, inclusion-exclusion, mahalanobis-distance, philosophy, analytic-geometry, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, wreath-product, partitions, geometric-construction, variance, euclidean-algorithm, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood, dispersive-pde, modulus-theorem, tangent-line, ordinals, linear-algebra, finite-groups, pell-type-equations, fourier-transform, matroids, paradoxes, infinite-product, projectile-motion, simulink, associativity, integral-transforms, modular-forms, exponential-distribution, operads, angle, cross-product, continuity, uniform-continuity, bayesian-network, measure-theory, semigroups, orlicz-spaces, monoid, group-theory, fisher-information, confidence-interval, lie-algebroids, quantum-mechanics, wavelets, trigonometric-integrals, discontinuous-functions, density-function, fixed-point-arithmetics, trigonometric-equations, python, real-analysis, maxima-minima, sturm-liouville, notation, kakeya-sets, rationality-testing, cantor-set, determinant, fourier-series, gaussian-integral, slope, incompleteness, vector-auto-regression, polynomial-congruences, bochner-spaces, singular-integrals, irreducible-polynomials, fair-division, arzela-ascoli, programming, cauchy-sequences, gram-schmidt, matrix-calculus, general-topology, exponents, logistic-regression, change-of-basis, binary-operations, borel-cantelli-lemmas, spherical-coordinates, discrete-logarithms, gradient-descent, riemann-integration, inverse-function, integral-equations, soft-question, neural-networks, publishing, multivariable-calculus, integral-operators, poisson-process, polygons, stochastic-pde, vector-analysis, separation-axioms, z-transform, conjunctive-normal-form, subgradient, positive-definite, convergence, convolution, initial-value-problems, compression, cycloid, characteristic-functions, interval-arithmetic, lebesgue-integral, perfect-numbers, proof-verification, laurent-series, functional-analysis, spherical-geometry, field-theory, extension-field, integral-extensions, commutative-algebra, parametric, axioms, metric-spaces, valuation-theory, galois-theory, galois-cohomology, lp-spaces, complex-integration, normed-spaces, proof-explanation, lipschitz-functions, local-time, electromagnetism, symmetric-groups, compactness, jordan-normal-form, multiplicative-function, matrix-rank, limsup-and-liminf, distribution-theory, summation-method, finite-fields, matrix-decomposition, potential-theory, zariski-topology, computational-science, chessboard, rkhs, inner-product-space, ring-theory, geometric-inequalities, infinitesimals, multiple-integral, iterated-integrals, linear-regression, generalized-inverse, transport-equation, wave-equation, relation-algebra, weak-convergence, norm, group-homomorphism, nonlinear-system, branch-points, spherical-trigonometry, dissection, set-valued-analysis, summation-by-parts, sequent-calculus, multisets, rotations, parametrization, elementary-functions, uniform-convergence, piecewise-continuity, geometric-group-theory, fractal-analysis, wiener-measure, discriminant, contour-integration, bootstrap-sampling, geometric-measure-theory, telescopic-series, parity, tridiagonal-matrices, dimension-theory, transcendental-functions, entire-functions, fixed-point-iteration, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol, hausdorff-measure, cyclotomic-polynomials, measurable-functions, algebraic-combinatorics, lebesgue-measure, abstract-algebra, coordinate-systems, lagrange-interpolation, surface-integrals, minimal-polynomials, invariance, hardy-spaces, online-resources, orthonormal, projection-matrices, divisible-groups, bisection, analysis, residue-calculus, sampling-theory, hermite-polynomials, orthogonality, mobius-function, coincidences, products, uniform-integrability, bernoulli-polynomials, stability-theory, standard-error, line-integrals, abelian-groups, banach-algebras, trees, invariant-subspace, sparse-matrices, chi-squared, combinatorial-group-theory, banach-spaces, compact-operators, number-comparison, mathematicians, math-history, banach-fixed-point, fixed-point-theorems, mathcad, axiom-of-choice, coxeter-groups, root-systems, graph-laplacian, convex-geometry, polytopes, noncommutative-algebra, tetration, solid-geometry, polyhedra, nonlinear-analysis, elliptic-functions, lucas-numbers, orthogonal-polynomials, finite-geometry, cylindrical-coordinates, primitive-roots, hidden-markov-models, non-convex-optimization, hilbert-spaces, triangulated-categories, borel-sets, sylow-theory, differential, reference-works, von-neumann-algebras, injective-module, elliptic-integrals, cumulants, dihedral-groups, pade-approximation, arc-length, group-isomorphism, complete-spaces, transition-matrix, surreal-numbers, reflection, functional-calculus, connectedness, celestial-mechanics, baire-category, matching-theory, spherical-harmonics, noneuclidean-geometry, change-of-variable, decision-trees, characteristics, page-rank, quiver, symbology, palindrome, graph-connectivity, popular-math, filters, infinite-groups, terminology, greens-theorem, substitution, algebraic-groups, cyclic-groups, rolles-theorem, computer-vision, mellin-transform, metric-geometry, universal-algebra, trace, math-review, upper-lower-bounds, research, boolean-ring, diagonalization, condition-number, rounding-error, robotics, additive-combinatorics, data-sufficiency, stirling-numbers, monomial-ideals, spectral-theory, descent, knot-theory, elliptic-curves, divergence, voronoi-diagram, vector-spaces, maximal-and-prime-ideals, eulerian-path, directed-graphs, schwartz-space, well-orders, scalar-fields, quadratic-reciprocity, projective-module, learning, ordered-fields, topos-theory, semialgebraic-geometry, localization, vector-lattices, pointwise-convergence, simple-functions, barycentric-coordinates, affine-geometry, ultrafilter, hyperreal, nonstandard-analysis, rouches-theorem, modules, graded-modules, principal-ideal-domains, flatness, semi-simple-rings, lie-algebra-cohomology, category-theory, enriched-category-theory, analytic-functions, coherent-rings, noetherian, group-schemes, krull-dimension, integer-lattices, monotone-functions, p-groups, analyticity, ring-homomorphism, bit-strings, distribution-of-primes, riemann-stieltjes, coprime, locus, picard-scheme, schemes, affine-schemes, projective-schemes, differential-games, splitting-field, finsler-geometry, extreme-value-theorem, filtrations, heat-equation, catastrophic-cancellation, etale-cohomology, braidings, comodules, hopf-algebras, convex-cone, euler-maclaurin, theta-functions, bruhat-tits-theory, lambda-rings, unique-factorization-domains, radical-equations, sudoku, quartic-equations, dedekind-domain, global-dimension, career-development, regular-rings, lecture-notes, lmis, sequence-of-function, matrix-completion, bergman-spaces, moment-problem, uniform-spaces, duality-theorems, cauchy-principal-value, transformational-geometry, calculus-identities, hecke-algebras, equicontinuity, lotteries, profinite-groups, jordan-algebras, cayley-hamilton, symmetric-matrices, linearization, ideals, gradient-flows, solid-of-revolution, transpose, mobius-inversion, verma-modules, kronecker-product, jensen-inequality, sylvester-equation, singularvalues, multivalued-functions, ramification, semiring, integral-inequality, variational-inequalities, weak-topology, absolute-continuity, algebraic-equations, rounding-unit, poissons-equation, ramsey-theory, convex-hulls, projection, algebraic-numbers, semigroup-of-operators, weighted-least-squares, topological-vector-spaces, integral-domain, orthogonal-matrices, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, formal-power-series, curves, holomorphic-functions, bivariate-distributions, generalizedeigenvector, integrable-systems, hypergraphs, stationary-point, harmonic-functions, quadrature, perfect-squares, euler-sums, holder-inequality, pronunciation, soddy-circles, bell-numbers, frobenius-method, decidability, circulant-matrices, polylogarithm, synthetic-differential-geometry, chaitin-constant, locally-compact-groups, the-baire-space, topological-semigroups, roots-of-unity, closed-map, galerkin-methods, quasiconformal-maps, elementary-probability, gray-code, fermat-numbers, auction-theory, diagram-chasing, inverselaplace, cauchy-product, finite-difference-methods, prime-twins, cauchy-problem, young-inequality, crystallography, fixedpoints, naive-bayes, mersenne-numbers, finite-semigroups, reduced-residue-system, secant, matrix-exponential, sos, congruence-relations, envelope, gaussian-integers, eisenstein-integers, procrustes-problem, normal-subgroups, cauchy-integral-formula, monomial-function, machine-precision, cross-sections, littlewood-paley-theory, conditional-convergence, birthday, mean-curvature-flows, data-structure, euler-method, pattern-matching, kronecker-symbol, binary-programming, perfect-powers, hamilton-jacobi-equation, variational-analysis, reduction-of-order-ode, disjunctive-normal-form, oracles, nets, rigid-transformation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, hadamard-matrices, censoring, frobenius-groups, truncation-error, eigenfunctions, non-linear-dynamics, matrixpencil, finite-rings, artinian, inversive-geometry, hurwitz-matrices, field-trace, solid-angle, fusion-systems, combinatorial-number-theory, even-and-odd-extensions

I obtained these lists by going to the main page, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> then entering

```
$("#interestingTags a").map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get().join(", ")
```

and

```
$("#ignoredTags a").map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get().join(", ")
```

respectively.

Comment: I'm guessing this is supposed to reveal posts tagged with your Favorite Tags.  That's how it seems to work for me (on the main site).

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you have favorite tags on this site? Is there a list of tags "tagged with ... " above the search box after you try?

Comment: @if....  Good idea. But I checked, and OP has numerous favorite and still more ignored tags. Moreover, an empty list of favorite tags  seems to be considered as all being favorite (for search).

Comment: Perhaps "Hide ignored tags" trumps existing favourite tags, and all recent questions have at least one of your ignored tags?

Comment: @DanielFischer I think the search would be over all questions not just recent ones, and the display of the search results does not seem to take the hidden ones into account. Thus, for this to be the case there would have to be no question at all  that matches the parameters.

Comment: Another guess: the site sets an undocumented limit for the number of tags in search, for performance reasons.

Comment: Probably not the answer but did you search with the quotation marks(") if so try without them (also did you try clicking on the link that Martian edited in?)

Comment: @kingW3: I only included the quotation marks in the question, I did not use them in search. I get the same result when I click on the link Martin Sleziak edited in.

Comment: It seems that this stumped some experienced users - neither quid nor Daniel Fischer have an explanation. Could you perhaps include some additional information? (Maybe screenshot of what you get when you search, screenshot of favorite tags, screenshot of ignored tags.) I know that mods can get to this, but there is some chance that also a regular user could help with more information.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I have added a screenshot of the beginning and end of the page when I do the aforementioned search (I think I left out about 10 other screens worth of tags).

Comment: Do you happen to remember when was the last time the "intags:mine" search worked for you and whether you were adding some tags since then?

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I don't remember, sorry. I have definitely been adding tags (mostly ignored) since then.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I cannot suggest any better explanation other than offered both in the above comments and [in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6612052#6612052). Maybe you have too many tags there...? And I do not really have an easy way to test this myself. Maybe as an approximation you can use the link from my post while this does not work. (And it is possible that if you publish the list of your favorite and ignored tags, somebody might try to experiment with this a bit.)

Comment: BTW the answers here might give some suggestion how to get list of all favorite/ignored tags in some sensible format: [Is it possible to see favorite tags of another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303972) and [Is it possible to list favourite/ignored tags alphabetically?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16394).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I have added lists of my favorite and ignored tags.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Are the does in the list ingored tags some kind of mistake? I mean this: "markov-process, …, matlab,"

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I don't know why they appear. There are no other ignored tags between those two.

Comment: I have posted the question whether there is a limit: [Does “intags:mine” no longer work above certain number of favorite/ignored tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306314) And I have also left a few comment [here in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2018/1/28).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have carried this as an experiment - perhaps it could serve as an additional datapoint which might help the OP or somebody else with further investigation.

I have tried including the tags from the [curent revision of the question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/27707/5) as my favorite tags, and start adding *some* of the ignored tags. The results of the experiments are below.

Incidentally, it stopped working at 1023 ignored tags; if I am counting correctly. One possible explanation could that this number is actually the limit for number of ignored tags.

I have also asked on the Meta Stack Exchange: [Does “intags:mine” no longer work above certain number of favorite/ignored tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306314) We will see whether we get some official confirmation that there is a limit for this.

---

Maybe somebody will suggest a better solution, but what I can suggest is try one of the following:

- Reduce the number of your ignored tags so that it is working again, or
- For searching, instead of list of tags you can use simply a search with the tags listed. So you can save links like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-curves+or+algebraic-geometry+or+algebraic-topology+or+almost-complex+or+characteristic-classes+or+classifying-spaces+or+clifford-algebras+or+compact-manifolds+or+complex-geometry+or+complex-manifolds+or+differential-forms+or+differential-geometry+or+differential-topology+or+exterior-algebra+or+fiber-bundles+or+geometric-topology+or+grassmannian+or+holomorphic-bundles+or+homology-cohomology+or+homotopy-theory+or+kahler-manifolds+or+lie-derivative+or+lie-groups+or+manifolds+or+low-dimensional-topology+or+mobius-transformation+or+multilinear-algebra+or+principal-bundles+or+riemann-surfaces+or+riemannian-geometry+or+several-complex-variables+or+sheaf-cohomology+or+smooth-manifolds+or+symplectic-geometry+or+symplectic-linear-algebra+or+vector-bundles+or+k-theory+or+topological-k-theory+or+holonomy+or+tensors+or+cobordism+or+connections+or+bostruction-theory+or+gauge-theory+or+4-manifolds+or+spin-geometry+or+transversality+or+surgery-theory+or+geometric-algebras+or+covering-spaces+or+rational-homotopy-theory+-statistical-inference+-math-software+-markov-chains+-markov-process+-matlab+-stochastic-analysis+-stochastic-processes+-signal-analysis+-computer-science+-signal-processing+-mathematical-modeling+-statistics+-model-theory+-maple+-mathematica+-gap+-magma+-magma-cas+-numerical-methods+-numerical-linear-algebra+-numerical-optimization+-na.numerical-analysis+-numerical-analysis+-fuzzy-logic+-fuzzy-set+-p-adic-number-theory+-computer-algebra-systems+-abelian-categories+-monoidal-categories+-higher-category-theory+-model-categories+-random-variables+-functions+-graphing-functions+-normal-distribution+-trigonometry+-recurrence-relations+-computability+-lambda-calculus+-stationary-processes+-average+-data-analysis+-data-mining+-implicit-differentiation+-nonlinear-optimization+-network+-network-flow+-floating-point+-descriptive-statistics+-set-theory+-formal-languages+-context-free-grammar+-regular-language) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=test+%5Balgebraic-curves%5D+or+%5Balgebraic-geometry%5D+or+%5Balgebraic-topology%5D+or+%5Balmost-complex%5D+or+%5Bcharacteristic-classes%5D+or+%5Bclassifying-spaces%5D+or+%5Bclifford-algebras%5D+or+%5Bcompact-manifolds%5D+or+%5Bcomplex-geometry%5D+or+%5Bcomplex-manifolds%5D+or+%5Bdifferential-forms%5D+or+%5Bdifferential-geometry%5D+or+%5Bdifferential-topology%5D+or+%5Bexterior-algebra%5D+or+%5Bfiber-bundles%5D+or+%5Bgeometric-topology%5D+or+%5Bgrassmannian%5D+or+%5Bholomorphic-bundles%5D+or+%5Bhomology-cohomology%5D+or+%5Bhomotopy-theory%5D+or+%5Bkahler-manifolds%5D+or+%5Blie-derivative%5D+or+%5Blie-groups%5D+or+%5Bmanifolds%5D+or+%5Blow-dimensional-topology%5D+or+%5Bmobius-transformation%5D+or+%5Bmultilinear-algebra%5D+or+%5Bprincipal-bundles%5D+or+%5Briemann-surfaces%5D+or+%5Briemannian-geometry%5D+or+%5Bseveral-complex-variables%5D+or+%5Bsheaf-cohomology%5D+or+%5Bsmooth-manifolds%5D+or+%5Bsymplectic-geometry%5D+or+%5Bsymplectic-linear-algebra%5D+or+%5Bvector-bundles%5D+or+%5Bk-theory%5D+or+%5Btopological-k-theory%5D+or+%5Bholonomy%5D+or+%5Btensors%5D+or+%5Bcobordism%5D+or+%5Bconnections%5D+or+%5Bbostruction-theory%5D+or+%5Bgauge-theory%5D+or+%5B4-manifolds%5D+or+%5Bspin-geometry%5D+or+%5Btransversality%5D+or+%5Bsurgery-theory%5D+or+%5Bgeometric-algebras%5D+or+%5Bcovering-spaces%5D+or+%5Brational-homotopy-theory%5D+-%5Bstatistical-inference%5D+-%5Bmath-software%5D+-%5Bmarkov-chains%5D+-%5Bmarkov-process%5D+-%5Bmatlab%5D+-%5Bstochastic-analysis%5D+-%5Bstochastic-processes%5D+-%5Bsignal-analysis%5D+-%5Bcomputer-science%5D+-%5Bsignal-processing%5D+-%5Bmathematical-modeling%5D+-%5Bstatistics%5D+-%5Bmodel-theory%5D+-%5Bmaple%5D+-%5Bmathematica%5D+-%5Bgap%5D+-%5Bmagma%5D+-%5Bmagma-cas%5D+-%5Bnumerical-methods%5D+-%5Bnumerical-linear-algebra%5D+-%5Bnumerical-optimization%5D+-%5Bna.numerical-analysis%5D+-%5Bnumerical-analysis%5D+-%5Bfuzzy-logic%5D+-%5Bfuzzy-set%5D+-%5Bp-adic-number-theory%5D+-%5Bcomputer-algebra-systems%5D) and modify them according to your needs. Still, you will get much less tags there, since there is a limit on the length of url. (And maybe if you are searching among those tags, it might be sufficient to [use only favorite tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=test+%5Balgebraic-curves%5D+or+%5Balgebraic-geometry%5D+or+%5Balgebraic-topology%5D+or+%5Balmost-complex%5D+or+%5Bcharacteristic-classes%5D+or+%5Bclassifying-spaces%5D+or+%5Bclifford-algebras%5D+or+%5Bcompact-manifolds%5D+or+%5Bcomplex-geometry%5D+or+%5Bcomplex-manifolds%5D+or+%5Bdifferential-forms%5D+or+%5Bdifferential-geometry%5D+or+%5Bdifferential-topology%5D+or+%5Bexterior-algebra%5D+or+%5Bfiber-bundles%5D+or+%5Bgeometric-topology%5D+or+%5Bgrassmannian%5D+or+%5Bholomorphic-bundles%5D+or+%5Bhomology-cohomology%5D+or+%5Bhomotopy-theory%5D+or+%5Bkahler-manifolds%5D+or+%5Blie-derivative%5D+or+%5Blie-groups%5D+or+%5Bmanifolds%5D+or+%5Blow-dimensional-topology%5D+or+%5Bmobius-transformation%5D+or+%5Bmultilinear-algebra%5D+or+%5Bprincipal-bundles%5D+or+%5Briemann-surfaces%5D+or+%5Briemannian-geometry%5D+or+%5Bseveral-complex-variables%5D+or+%5Bsheaf-cohomology%5D+or+%5Bsmooth-manifolds%5D+or+%5Bsymplectic-geometry%5D+or+%5Bsymplectic-linear-algebra%5D+or+%5Bvector-bundles%5D+or+%5Bk-theory%5D+or+%5Btopological-k-theory%5D+or+%5Bholonomy%5D+or+%5Btensors%5D+or+%5Bcobordism%5D+or+%5Bconnections%5D+or+%5Bbostruction-theory%5D+or+%5Bgauge-theory%5D+or+%5B4-manifolds%5D+or+%5Bspin-geometry%5D+or+%5Btransversality%5D+or+%5Bsurgery-theory%5D+or+%5Bgeometric-algebras%5D+or+%5Bcovering-spaces%5D+or+%5Brational-homotopy-theory%5D) - after omitting the ignored tags the search query is much shorter and less likely to cause problems.)

---

When I added all ignored tags until (and including) [poissons-equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poissons-equation), the search worked as expected.

[image: Screenshot]

And simply by after adding one more tag [ramsey-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramsey-theory) I get zero results.

[image: Screenshot]

Just to try whether it is some significance to this specific tag, I have removed this tag from the ignored tags and replaced it with [combinatorial-number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorial-number-theory). Again I came empty-handed.

[image: Sceenshot]